# Как сделать заданный стиль таблицы Excel программно

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

Как сделать вот такой стиль таблицы программно на C#.

[image: Вот такой стиль]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это код с использованием либы [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/). Сначала укажите ваш диапазон в `modelRange`, далее создаете таблицу на основе указанного диапазона и применяете к ней границы. В `ExcelBorderStyle` найдете все типы границ.

```
  string modelRange = "D1:F6";
    var modelTable = worksheet.Cells[modelRange];

    // Assign borders
    modelTable.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    modelTable.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    modelTable.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    modelTable.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
```

Answer (score 0):

В своем случае сделал так:

```
Excel.Workbook objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(sPath);
Excel.Worksheet objWS = (Excel.Worksheet)objWB.Sheets[1];

Excel.Range eRange = objWS.UsedRange;

eRange.EntireRow.AutoFit();
eRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

Excel.Borders border;
```

При добавлении записи в таблицу делаю границу у всех ячеек

```
border = eRange.Borders;
border.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
```

а в последнем проходе делаю внешнюю границу

```
border = eRange.Borders;
border.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
border[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDouble;
border[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDouble;
border[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDouble;
border[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDouble;
```

Вдруг кому-нибудь пригодится...